# No data in sales transactions grid

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-grid, transaction

In my magento 2.3.6 I have successfully completed an order but in sales -> transactions grid there is no data appearing.
I am using three payment methods
1- CCAvenue Net banking
2- Cash on delivery
3- Money Order

Have completed the order by using these payment methods, still no data appearing.
Cron is also installed using

```
php bin/magento cron:install
php bin/magento cron:run
```

What may be the reason?
I thought COD and Money order are offline payment methods that's why data is not available, Now using CCAvenue Net Banking still data not appearing.

Comment: Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Grid Settings and set Asynchronous indexing to “disable”. after change this clear cache and check order visible or not

Comment: @RkRathod Asynchronous indexing is already disabled and the store is in the developer mode, still not showing

Comment: any error in exception.log or system.log ???

Comment: here is the system.log https://imgur.com/a/SyxPsXu after running `` bin/magento cron:run``